# Actor.setx = FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 2967

Tags: java, android, libgdx, actor

I am really pulling my hairs our with this funny issue. I am doing my loadingscreen. The smallBox will move to right according to asset manager loading percentage. I received "FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 2967" when i try to setX() for my smallBox. I tried resize() but no luck, same error. I am not sure where i went wrong.

Here is my code:

```
public class LoadingScreen extends AbstractScreen {

private Image bigBox, smallBox;
private Stage stage;
float loadingPercent=0f;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture loadingTexture;

public LoadingScreen(game game) {
    super(game);

    // load asset here
    Gdx.app.log("gamelog", "assetManager.load()");
    game.assetManager.load("img/loading.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
    game.assetManager.load("img/splash.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
}

@Override
public void show() {
    stage = new Stage();

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    loadingTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("img/loadingTexture.png"));
    loadingTexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    TextureRegion bigBoxTr = new TextureRegion(loadingTexture, 0, 0, 800, 480);
    TextureRegion smallBoxTr = new TextureRegion(loadingTexture, 0, 790, 800, 110);

    Image bigBox = new Image(bigBoxTr);
    Image smallBox = new Image(smallBoxTr);

    smallBox.setX(-800);
    smallBox.setY(160);

    bigBox.setX(0);
    bigBox.setY(0);

    stage.addActor(bigBox);
    stage.addActor(smallBox);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // Clear the screen
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    loadingPercent = Interpolation.linear.apply(loadingPercent, game.assetManager.getProgress(), 0.1f);
    Gdx.app.log("gamelog", "LoadingScreen: =" + (-800+(int)(loadingPercent*800*2)) + " getProgress" + game.assetManager.getProgress());

    smallBox.setX(-800+(int)(loadingPercent*800*2)); //<------ problem point
    smallBox.invalidate();

    if (game.assetManager.update()) {
        Gdx.app.log("gamelog", "LoadingScreen: before calling SplashScreen =" + (-800+(int)(loadingPercent*800*2)) + " getProgress" + game.assetManager.getProgress());
        game.setScreen(new SplashScreen(game));
    }

    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();

}
```

error log on LogCat

```
11-01 22:08:54.308: I/awesomegame(24701): LoadingScreen: =-800 getProgress0.0
11-01 22:08:54.318: D/memalloc(24701): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51f68000 size:10297344 offset:9527296
11-01 22:08:54.328: W/dalvikvm(24701): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c2ca68)
11-01 22:08:54.328: E/AndroidRuntime(24701): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 2967
11-01 22:08:54.328: E/AndroidRuntime(24701): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-01 22:08:54.328: E/AndroidRuntime(24701):    at com.example.awesomegame.screens.LoadingScreen.render(LoadingScreen.java:128)
11-01 22:08:54.328: E/AndroidRuntime(24701):    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
11-01 22:08:54.328: E/AndroidRuntime(24701):    at com.example.awesomegame.somegame.render(somegame.java:25)
11-01 22:08:54.328: E/AndroidRuntime(24701):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:487)
11-01 22:08:54.328: E/AndroidRuntime(24701):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1463)
11-01 22:08:54.328: E/AndroidRuntime(24701):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1217)
```

However, bigBox display correctly when i comment out line "smallBox.setX(-800+(int)(loadingPercent*800*2)); //<------ problem point". I thought is the float/int issue, however, according to LogCat (when line commented out):

```
11-01 22:03:29.261: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: =-800 getProgress0.0
11-01 22:03:29.301: D/memalloc(24283): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52e94000 size:4255744 offset:3485696 fd:67
11-01 22:03:29.301: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: =-800 getProgress0.0
11-01 22:03:29.311: D/memalloc(24283): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x533c7000 size:5025792 offset:4255744 fd:70
11-01 22:03:29.321: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: =-800 getProgress0.0
11-01 22:03:29.331: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: =-800 getProgress0.0
...
11-01 22:03:30.362: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: =-38 getProgress0.5
11-01 22:03:30.512: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: =-34 getProgress0.5
11-01 22:03:30.532: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: =-31 getProgress0.5
11-01 22:03:30.532: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: =-28 getProgress0.5
11-01 22:03:30.552: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: =-25 getProgress0.5
11-01 22:03:30.572: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: =-23 getProgress0.5
11-01 22:03:30.572: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: =-21 getProgress0.5
11-01 22:03:30.592: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: =-19 getProgress0.5
11-01 22:03:30.612: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: =-17 getProgress0.5
11-01 22:03:30.612: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: =-15 getProgress0.5
11-01 22:03:30.672: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: =-14 getProgress0.5
11-01 22:03:30.692: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: =-12 getProgress0.5
11-01 22:03:30.872: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: =-11 getProgress0.5
11-01 22:03:30.882: I/awesomegame(24283): LoadingScreen: before calling SplashScreen =-11 getProgress1.0
```

it seems that the working formula is right. I have been stuck on this issue for days and not sure where and how to fix it.

Thank you very much, any help is much appreciated.

Regards
Zii

Comment: Use your debugger to find the problem. `smallBox.setX(-800+(int)(lo...` can only throw a `NullPointerException` if `smallBox` or `loadingPercent` are `null`. `loadingPercent` can actually not be `null`, because its type is `float` and not `Float`. So `smallBox` has to be `null`.

Comment: Thanks Noone. Yup, you are right, I just tested, it seems that `smallBox` is Null. do you have any recommendation how i should fix this issue? and does it really matters `loadingPercent` is `float` or `Float`? what are the differences?

Comment: Judging by the given code, `smallBox` cannot be `null`. It's once set in `show()` and then never changed (at least in the code I can see here, so the problem has to be somewhere else). And yes, it makes a difference. `float` cannot be `null`, but `Float` can. Let's say you have `Float foo = null;`. Then both the following lines will throw a `NullPointerException`: 1) `Float bar = foo * 10;` 2) `float bar = (float) foo;`

Comment: it seems that smallBox is null. i tested it using the follow code 

if (smallBox != null)
   Gdx.app.log("awesomegame", "LoadingScreen: smallBox != null");
  else
   Gdx.app.log("awesomegame", "LoadingScreen: smallBox == null");

  if (loadingPercent != null)
   Gdx.app.log("awesomegame", "LoadingScreen: loadingPercent != null");
  else
   Gdx.app.log("awesomegame", "LoadingScreen: loadingPercent == null");
the logcat displayed 
11-02 07:15:03.181: I/catlandwarriors(28457): LoadingScreen: yellowWindows == null

Comment: yellowWindows == null? huh? You should really start to get comfortable with the debugger. It is much more powerful and fast than debugging with log outputs.

Comment: i re-enable all logging process, it seems that:
I/awesomegame(29728): game: Creating game on Android
I/awesomegame(29728): game: setScreen( new LoadingScreen(this) )
I/awesomegame(29728): LoadingScreen:  assetManager.load()
I/awesomegame(29728): LoadingScreen: Image smallBox
I/awesomegame(29728): game: set screen to: LoadingScreen
I/awesomegame(29728): game: Resizing game
I/awesomegame(29728): LoadingScreen: =-800 getProgress0.0
I/awesomegame(29728): LoadingScreen: smallBox: in render() == null
I/awesomegame(29728): LoadingScreen: loadingPercent != null

Comment: I/awesomegame(29728): LoadingScreen: =-800 getProgress0.0
...
I/awesomegame(29728): LoadingScreen: smallBox: in render() == null
I/awesomegame(29728): LoadingScreen: loadingPercent != null
I/awesomegame(29728): LoadingScreen: before calling SplashScreen =-1 getProgress1.0
I/awesomegame(29728): SplashScreen: show()
I/awesomegame(29728): SplashScreen: resize()
I/awesomegame(29728): game: set screen to: SplashScreen
I/awesomegame(29728): AbstractScreen: pause(): SplashScreen
I/awesomegame(29728): game: Pausing game
I/awesomegame(29728): SplashScreen: hide()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem came from. after tracing each step, it seems that the smallbox is being disposed between LoadingScreen and AbstractScreen. the solution is to add "this." as the prefix to the smallbox.

anyway, thanks for you help anyway, @noone